# Como faço para fazer uma pesquisa entre vários db e apresentar o resultado na própria pagina?

Tags: php, javascript

No `MySQL` tenho um banco de dados e dentro dele tenho a tabela *student*, e gostaria de pesquisar em outro banco que é idêntico ao primeiro, porém, com informações diferentes, e gostaria de saber em qual dos bancos o *aluno* está criado.

Essa pesquisa exibiria o resultado na própria página, e estou com essa dúvida e não estou conseguindo desenrolar isso.

Obs: *esse código pode ser em php ou em `JavaScript`*.

Comment: Crie duas conexões diferentes, na hora de executar a consulta especifique as repectivas conexões. Está usando o MySQLi ou o PDO?

Comment: o Mysql, mais teria outra forma, pois se caso tiver varias escolas ficaria varias conexões?

Comment: Todas as databases estão no mesmo servidor?

Comment: Não seria só usar o `mysqli_select_db` e selecionar outro banco de dados?

Comment: Tem diferença entre pedir ajuda e pedir pra fazer por você. **Poste o código**: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se as databases estiverem todas no mesmo servidor, basta informar o nome da database antes do nome da tabela.

Por exemplo, Supondo que você tenha duas databases, DB1 e DB2:

Exemplo de query consultando DB1:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.Student WHERE ...
```

Exemplo de query consultando DB2:

```
SELECT * FROM DB2.Student WHERE ...
```

Exemplo de query usando as duas:

```
SELECT s1.nome, s2.nome FROM DB1.Student as s1
JOIN DB2.Student as s2 ON s2.id = s1.id
```

Comment: Obrigado leo_ap isso me deu uma luz de como resolver o meu problema